# Exclude child checkbox from parent toggle

Tags: jquery

I have a series of content and header divs to display some data. In addition each header has a checkbox.

```
<div id="content-1">
    <div class="head"><input type="checkbox" name="check-1"/> Header</div>
    <div class="content">Content</div>
</div>
<div id="content-2">...</div>
<div id="content-3">...</div>
```

I use to following jQuery to show/hide a content div by clicking on the respective header div.

```
$(".head").toggle(
    function(){ $(this).nextAll().slideDown('200'); },
    function(){ $(this).nextAll().slideUp('200'); }
);
```

The problem is that clicking the checkbox shows/hides the content div and the checkbox can not be checked/unchecked. I want the content toggle to only occur when clicking the head div, and for the checkbox to function as normal.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're experiencing is due to the fact you have two click events for only one handler. Your two events are: clicking the head-div and clicking a checkbox WITHIN that head-div. As you have only specified one handler, bot events will be delegated to that one (as your checkboxes are contained by the head-div) and thus will toggle both.

You need to add a handler, which will act more specifcly. With a selector like this:

```
$(".head :checkbox").click(function(event){
$(this).attr('checked','checked');
});
```

EDIT: not tested, but I think this should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if `$(event.target).is('.head')` in order to do the toggle.

```
$('.head').toggle(
    function(e){ $(e.target).is('.head') &&
                     $(this).nextAll().slideDown('200') },
    function(e){ $(e.target).is('.head') &&
                     $(this).nextAll().slideUp('200') }
)
```

A cleaner option would be to check if `event.target` and `this` are different and then stop the event propagation. Otherwise, do the sliding.

```
$('.head').toggle(
    function(e){ e.target !== this ? e.stopPropagation()
                                   : $(this).nextAll().slideDown(200) },
    function(e){ e.target !== this ? e.stopPropagation()
                                   : $(this).nextAll().slideUp(200) }
)
```

I've not tested it, thoughit seems to me a reasonable solution.

UPDATE:

In fact, toggle calls preventDefault, so the solution should be something in this lines:

```
$('.head').bind('click', function(e){
    e.target !== this
        ? e.stopPropagation()
        : $(this).nextAll().slideToggle(200)
});
```

Comment: Thank you. Both solutions exclude the checkbox from the toggle function. However, the checkbox no longer functions correctly.

Comment: If I remember correctly, $.toggle does a call to preventDefault, so this is preventing the checkbox for being check. I'd suggest to move to bind('click') and use slideToggle instead.